# Trigger Similar JQuery element on different span element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So ideally what I want to have happen is trigger an identical function that I already have in my email span/form element, however I'm new to JQuery and can't quite wrap my head around it. Anyways, so in my email function, it essentially grabs the user input and and triggers the css class "form span error" which turns the span element red. Until the user inputs the "@" symbol, the "form span valid" is triggered. I would additionally like JQuery to trigger the "form span.error" rule on the productId forum/span element. Could please someone explain? ***Here's the CSS rule for the span:***

```
#form span {
    border-radius: 20px;
    margin-left:15px;
    padding: 8px 35px;
    background: #FA5700;
    color:#faf3bc;
}
#form span.valid {
    background-color :#c0ce51;
    color: #faf3bc;
}
#form span.error {
    background-color:#b0240f;
    color: #faf3bc;
}
```

***HTML/JQUERY:***

```
   <form method="post" action="contact-thanks.php">

                    <p>
                            <label for="name">Name:</label>
                            <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="required" value="<?php if (isset($name)) { echo htmlspecialchars($name); } ?>">
                            <span>Please enter your name</span>
                    </p>

                    <p>
                            <label for="email">Email:</label>
                            <input type="text" name="email" id="email" class="required" value="<?php if(isset($email)) { echo htmlspecialchars($email); } ?>">
                            <span>Please enter a valid email address</span>
                    </p>

                    <p> 
                            <label for="productId">Product Id:</label>
                            <input type="text" name="productId" id="productId" class="required" value="<?php if(isset($productId)) { echo htmlspecialchars($productId); } ?>">
                            <span>Please enter a ID number</span>
                    </p>
               <p class="submit">
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn-submit">
                </p>
            </form>

</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var $submit = $(".submit input");
        var $required = $(".required");
        function containsBlanks(){
            var blanks = $required.map(function(){ return $(this).val() == "";});
            return $.inArray(true, blanks) != -1;
        }
        //Checks for valid email
        function isValidEmail(email){
            return email.indexOf("@") != -1;
        }
        //Does not let the user submit if all text fields are not filled in
        function requiredFilledIn(){
            if(containsBlanks() || !isValidEmail($("#email").val())) 
                $submit.attr("disabled","disabled");
            else 
                $submit.removeAttr("disabled");
        }

        //Here's what I've tried, I'm playing around with it here for testing purposes
        //I'm afraid this syntax is terribly wrong  
        $("#productId").focus(function(){

            $(this).next().removeClass("valid").addClass("error");
        });
        $("#form span").hide();
        $("input,textarea").focus(function(){
            $(this).next().fadeIn("slow");
        }).blur(function(){
            $(this).next().fadeOut("slow");
        }).keyup(function(){
            //Check all required fields.
            requiredFilledIn();
        });

        $("#email").keyup(function(){
            //Check for a valid email.
            if(isValidEmail($(this).val()))
             $(this).next().removeClass("error").addClass("valid");
            else 
             $(this).next().removeClass("valid").addClass("error");
        });




        requiredFilledIn();
    </script>
```

Appreciate any help ahead of time!

Comment: I see you're trying to do custom form validation. It may be worthwhile to use jquery validation instead http://jqueryvalidation.org/

Comment: When do you want to trigger the productId error? As the user types? When they leave the field? What determines whether productId is valid or not? Does it have to be in a specific format?

Comment: @toxalot Ok so basically the product Id sends a PHP request to a JSON url. If the user enters in a invalid id, a PHP if statement gets triggered. That's when I want to trigger the JQuery product ID error.

Comment: @toxalot no it does not need to be in a specific format. Sorry, forgot to answer that.

Comment: @user3124081 - I noticed that you answered your question (but have since deleted the answer). Did your answer fix this? If it was correct and did solve your situation, can you please undelete it so future visitors will know this issue is resolved? Self-answers cannot be accepted in the first 48 hours of the question being asked, but then you may mark your answer as correct (if it resolves the issue).

Comment: @TravisJ Whoops sorry about that. Yes my answer did solve my problem. Check below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some simple experimenting, I figured it out. Here's the code if anyone is curious:

```
$("#productId").show(function(){
                $(this).next().fadeIn("slow").removeClass("valid").addClass("error");
            });
```

Comment: *note the "fade in" call isn't completely necessary as you all well know, just something I was looking for.